# Magic number in reflected gray code to binary conversion

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, magic-numbers, gray-code

I wrote a generic function to convert a binary reflected gray code to standard binary. I used an algorithm I found on [this page](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/gray-code-conversion). Here is the aforementioned algorithm:

```
unsigned short grayToBinary(unsigned short num)
{
        unsigned short temp = num ^ (num>>8);
        temp ^= (temp>>4);
        temp ^= (temp>>2);
        temp ^= (temp>>1);
        return temp;
}
```

Then I modified the code so that it would work for any standard `unsigned` type. Here is what I wrote:

```
template<typename Uint>
Uint grayToBinary(Uint value)
{
    for (Uint mask = sizeof(Uint)*4 ; mask ; mask >>= 1)
    {
        value ^= value >> mask;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The algorithm seems to work fine for every `unsigned` standard type. However, when writing it, I instinctively used `sizeof(Uint)*4` since it made sense that the end condition would depend on the type size, but the truth is that I have no idea what `sizeof(Uint)*4` actually represents. For now, it is a magic number that I wrote instinctively, but I am unable to explain why it works with `*4` and not with any other coefficient.

Does anybody know what this magic number actually correspond to?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you wrote this code, but don't understand why it works?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that's surprisingly common in CS

Comment: no, he's saying he *thinks* it's working.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qsLx1Ip.jpg

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, I adapted an already working code that I did not 100% understand and it happens to work (at least, all my unit tests work). I know, it's a shame^^"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`4` happens to be `8 / 2` [citation needed], or `CHAR_BIT / 2`.

Your gray code decoding algorithm start by taking the left half of the given integer type, and shifts it to the right half of the type, which happens to be `sizeof(type) * (CHAR_BIT / 2)` bits to the right, which is exactly what you are seeing.

As pointed out in the comments, `std::numeric_limits<type>::digits / 2` would be the more idiomatic solution for C++.

Comment: Shall I assume that `8` stands for `CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: 8 stands for the number of bits in a byte.

Comment: So does `CHAR_BIT`. That's roughly what I had in mind :)

Comment: By the way, for whoever would like an idiomatic C++ solution, instead of `sizeof(type) * (CHAR_BIT / 2)`, it would be better to use `std::numeric_limits<type>::digits / 2`.

Comment: @Morwenn that's an excellent idea. would you mind if I added that to my answer?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I do not see a problem. I will be happy if people have access to the best possible answer :p